# oc4j session gets invalidated

Tags: java, session, vaadin, oc4j

We are developing a Vaadin application, running it on oc4j 10.1.3.
After implementing basic authentication, the user's session gets invalidated automatically, within the timeout (which is the default).
So, a user opens the Vaadin application and on one point there should be some data set as session attributes for an other servlet. However, at that time, we have an exception saying that the session in already invalidated. It is never called explicitly, maybe oc4j does it?
It was working fine before the authentication has been implemented.

```
Aug 13, 2012 4:21:27 PM com.vaadin.Application terminalError
SEVERE: Terminal error:
com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method buttonClick in com.mycompany.myapp$1 failed.
at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:530)
at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:164)
at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.fireEvent(AbstractComponent.java:1219)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:567)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button.changeVariables(Button.java:223)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.changeVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1460)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariableBurst(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1404)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1329)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:761)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(CommunicationManager.java:318)
at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:501)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
at com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:64)
at com.mycompany.myapp.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:44)
at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.invoke(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:644)
at com.evermind.server.http.ServletRequestDispatcher.forwardInternal(ServletRequestDispatcher.java:391)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.doProcessRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:908)
at com.evermind.server.http.HttpRequestHandler.processRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:458)
at com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:313)
at com.evermind.server.http.AJPRequestHandler.run(AJPRequestHandler.java:199)
at oracle.oc4j.network.ServerSocketReadHandler$SafeRunnable.run(ServerSocketReadHandler.java:260)
at com.evermind.util.ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor$MyWorker.run(ReleasableResourcePooledExecutor.java:303)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session was invalidated
at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindHttpSession.setAttribute(EvermindHttpSession.java:158)
at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindHttpSession.setAttribute(EvermindHttpSession.java:137)
at com.mycompany.myapp$1.buttonClick(MyPage.java:105)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0):

After implementing a HttpSessionListener, i've found that the session itself is valid. Something must be wrong on the Vaadin side, b/c setting the session as a variable in my Application implementation from a HttpServletRequestListener.onRequestStart method, that session instance is okay.